# EditText with PasswordTransformationMethod, keyboard gives suggestion revealing password

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In my android application, I have some `EditText`s. Those `EditText`s will serve as password fields, but I've not marked them as password fields in the attributes, so that the font of hint text matches the font of hint in normal `EditText` widgets.

The problem I have though is that the password is revealed in the keyboard suggestion while it is typed, although it is hidden as I've used:

```
EditText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

What should I do to disable those suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already fixed it, but didn't have time to come and answer the question.
For anyone who is struggling with this, adding the following attribute to the `EditText` will work:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use     android:inputType="textPassword"
and android:password="true"?

Comment: no I didn't use them because they'd mess up the "hint" font. The hint font becomes monospace, while normal EditTexts have hints with normal font. I used the transformation method instead

Comment: I just tried it and it won't work. The password is still showing at keyboard's suggestions.